# Delegate method to set cell text color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to **set the text color of a selected table view cell when the delegate has passed the information back** to the Parent View Controller.

Here is what I have:

```
-(void)reSelectTableRow:(NSUInteger)index{
    if(index < albumTracksArrayForTVC.count){
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
        [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:
         UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    NSLog(@"Delegate reSelectTableRow was called");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

However, neither of my attempts (`cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];` or `cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];`) seem to work.

Any ideas?

Here is how I set the highlighted text initially in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: `cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor brownColor];`.

Comment: You are reloading the table. This means that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is going to be called for all of the cells. Do you properly set the colors there? BTW - there is no reason to reload the table.

Comment: Ideally you'd have a kind of a model for your cells, and you'd mark your changes there. Then, after reloading that cell (no need to reload whole table) you'd setup it based on the values in the model in `tableVie:cellForRowAtIndexPath;`

Comment: @rmaddy I think you're comment helped me get to the right answer.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll mark it because it was an answer.  thanks!

Comment: @Losiowaty great tip, thanks!